# AngularJS - ng-Style not changing when updated in the directive

Tags: css, angularjs

So, here is a custom directive to resize an element *and it's contents* based on a screen size change. I can see that the value of 'scalify' is changing how I would like it to, but the style itself is not changing. I know that the styles work when applied with static values directly in the css file.

```
.directive("card", function(){
    return{
        restrict : "E",
        controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs){
            var w = this;
            window.onresize = function () {

                $scope.scalify = {
                    '-ms-zoom': window.innerHeight/675,
                    '-moz-transform': 'scale(' + window.innerHeight/675 + ')',
                    '-o-transform': 'scale(' + window.innerHeight/675 + ')',
                    '-webkit-transform': 'scale(' + window.innerHeight/675 + ')'
                };
                $scope.$apply();
            }
        }
    };
})
```

And here's how I use the ng-Style in the HTML

```
<card ng-style="scalify">
    ...
</card>
```

Comment: where are you calling ngStyle ?

Comment: I set ng-style="scalify" for an element in my HTML

Comment: Change window onresize into `angular.element(window).on('resize', function(){..});` otherwise you can bind only once to the resize event

Comment: you have to tell the directive that you are binding data scope: {
      ngStyle: '='
    }, can you try it ?

Comment: @jantimon making that change works to the extent that my current code works... so, I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @ThomasP1988 I've tried this, but it's doesn't seem to work either. I had this after setting scarify 

w.bind('card', function () {
                 scope.$apply();
             });

Comment: Hm everything else looks fine.. Could you please add a plunker?

Comment: Where do you specify the template?

Answer (score 0):

Hi please see here: http://run.plnkr.co/jfeF9NcPcGroNCsg/ probably you need to work a bit on your css transformation but style is changing when you change size of window as you wanted

```
app.directive("card", function($window) {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {


      scope.onResizeFunction = function() {
        //$scope.windowHeight = $window.innerHeight;
        // $scope.windowWidth = $window.innerWidth;

        var scalify = {
          '-ms-zoom': $window.innerHeight / 675,
          '-moz-transform': 'scale(' + $window.innerHeight / 675 + ')',
          '-o-transform': 'scale(' + $window.innerHeight / 675 + ')',
          '-webkit-transform': 'scale(' + $window.innerHeight / 675 + ')',
          'background-color': 'red'
        };


        element.css(scalify);
        console.log(element);
      };

      angular.element($window).bind('resize', function() {
        scope.onResizeFunction();
        scope.$apply();
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: hmmm. I guess it's just how I'm including the arithmetic ... the css with the hardcoded values works fine, but then it's not dynamic